# Plotting logistic maps

Tags: plotting, difference-equations

I have a question about plotting in *Mathematica* in general, and this particular recurrence relation as an example:

$\qquad x _{n+1} = rx_{n}(1-x_{n})$

How can I plot the following plots as shown below?

Here's where I am at so far, after searching the web for the code:

```
sol = RSolve[{x[n + 1] == 2.8*x[n]*(1 - x[n]), x[0] == 0.2}, x[n], n]
ListPlot[Table[{n, x[n] /. sol[[1]]}, {n, 1, 5}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Hue[1], PointSize[0.0125]}];
```

But this doesn't give me anything. Or should I use some alternative with NestList?

I have also tried the version below (another answer here on SE), but this simply doens't work (no output whatsoever, and this is a Web Diagram - not a simple logistic map that I am looking for):

```
logistic[α_, x0_] := 
  Module[{f}, 
    f[x_] := α x (1 - x);
    seq = NestList[f, x0, 100];
    p = Join @@ ({{#, #}, {##}} & @@@ Partition[seq, 2, 1]);
    Plot[{f[x], x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 1},
      Epilog -> {Thick, Opacity[0.6], Line[p]}, 
      ImageSize -> 500]];
```

The plots that I want to achieve:

[image: Example from Wolfram MathWorld]

Source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html

Comment: The reason the lostic function doesn't do anything is because it's a function and you have to call it. For example: `logistic[3.5, 0.1]`

Comment: First off, in your code you have a semicolon after the `Plot` command, so you won't get a plot.  Second, have a look at the output of `RSolve` - it does not give an analytic solution.  If you look at the mathworld page it says there is an analytic solution only for `r` equal to -2, 2, or 4, though the only attribution is to a private communication from Michael Trott.

Comment: So if you are working with other `r` values, then you need to generate the list numerically using `RecurrenceTable`

Comment: @JasonB What is shown on the plots are not *solutions*, they are several iterates of the logistic function $f$, that is, graphs of $f, f^2, f^3,\ldots$

Comment: @Artem - I was referring to the first lines of code in the post, and pointing out why they don't work

Comment: @Pavoo - for future reference you can usually download a Mathematica notebook from the relevant *MathWorld* page that will allow you to generate any of the plots there - although they were most all made in version 6 or before, so there is definite room to update the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, in your code

```
sol = RSolve[{x[n + 1] == 2.8*x[n]*(1 - x[n]), x[0] == 0.2}, x[n], n] ListPlot[Table[{n, x[n] /. sol[[1]]}, {n, 1, 5}], PlotStyle -> {Hue[1], PointSize[0.0125]}];
```

you have a semicolon after the `ListPlot` command, so you won't get a plot. Second, have a look at the output of [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) - it does not give an analytic formula.

```
sol = 
 RSolve[{x[n + 1] == 2.8*x[n]*(1 - x[n]), x[0] == 0.2}, x[n], n]
(* RSolve[{x[1 + n] == 2.8 (1 - x[n]) x[n], x[0] == 0.2}, x[n],
  n] *)
```

If you look at the [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html) page it says there is an analytic solution only for r equal to -2, 2, or 4, though the only attribution is to a private communication from Michael Trott (is there no other attribution available? Trott doesn't have an account on here....)

```
sol = RSolve[{x[n + 1] == #*x[n]*(1 - x[n]), x[0] == x0}, x[n], 
    n] & /@ {-2, 2, 4} 

{{{x[n] -> 1/2 (1 + 2 Cos[2^n ArcCos[1/2 (-1 + 2 x0)]])}}, {{x[n] -> 
    1/2 (1 - (1 - 2 x0)^2^n)}}, {{x[n] -> 
    1/2 (1 - Cos[2^n ArcCos[1 - 2 x0]])}}}
```

But you can just generate what you want with [`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html),

```
sol = 
 RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == 2.8*x[n]*(1 - x[n]), x[0] == 0.2}, 
  x, {n, 1, 5}]
(* {0.448, 0.692429, 0.596319, 0.674023, 0.615205} *)
```

And you can feed that list to listplot.  The second bit of code you have works fine, as shown by dionys in his answer.

For the plots you have at the end of your question, again use `RecurrenceTable`.  You don't even need to supply numeric values for `RecurrenceTable`.  The plots you look for can be easily found with

```
funcs = RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == r x[n] (1 - x[n]), x[0] == x0}, 
   x, {n, 1, 5}];
Plot[funcs /. r -> 3, {x0, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also vary the value of `r` to see the effect with `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[funcs /. r -> rr, {x0, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500, PlotLabel -> Row[{"r = ", rr}], 
  LabelStyle -> 18]
 , {rr, -2, 4, .01}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works, but it generates a cobweb plot:

```
logistic[2.8, 0.1]
```

[image]

For the visualization you want, take a closer look at the definitions of `f` and `seq` in the code you posted. The plots you want to generate shows `x[n]` vs. start value, `x0`, for iterations 1 through 5, at 4 different growth rates, `r`.

```
recurrenceList[r_, x0_, n_:50] := NestList[(r # (1 - #)) &, x0, n - 1]

Module[{fns, colors},
    colors = {Red, Yellow, Green, Blue, Lighter[Purple, 0.6]};
    GraphicsGrid@Partition[Table[
        fns = Table[recurrenceList[r, x][[n + 1]], {n, 1, 5}];
        Plot[fns, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> colors], {r, 1, 4}], 2]]
```

[image]